# Tried to move /home to new hdd, ended up deleting /home

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, mount, home-directory

Installed ubuntu to a new computer with one SSD and one HDD. The OS naturally I installed on the SSD. after using it for a week or so, configuring everything and downloading stuff I decided it's time to partition and mount the additional HDD. I partitioned the disk successfully and then I decided it would be a good idea to store the `/home` folder on the HDD. I followed [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving) guide for moving the `/home` folder. I completed the process and everything seemed to work fine. Then I realised I still have the `/media/home` folder, although it was just supposed to be temporal. So I looked again in that guide, and I saw that when it says to make this dir it also says you can delete it after you finished:

> 4. Save and Close the fstab file, then type the following command:
>
> `sudo mkdir /media/home`
>
> This command will create a new directory, later used for temporarily mounting the new partition. **At the end of the procedure this directory can be removed.**

I went on in doing so, and it seemed as if I can't delete that dir:

> `rm: cannot remove ‘/media/home’: Device or resource busy`

only it did delete `/home`.

I did install and configure some stuff before deleting `/home` but not many, so the failure burns but the damage is not crucial. I still want to know what am I doing wrong? wasn't I suppoesd to delete `/media/home`?

What should I do now? What should I do differently next time I follow this guide? help.

thanks!

Comment: What command did you use to delete?

Comment: `rm -rf /media/home`

Comment: This folder can't be deleted without `sudo`, if this was your creation command `sudo mkdir /media/home`

Comment: +1 but I can't see how it did delete it... Are you sure that is the exact command?

Comment: Yeah sorry it was `sudo rm -rf /media/home`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently your new home partition was mounted on *both* `/home` and `/media/home` when you ran `rm -r /media/home`.

`rm -r` removes a directory *recursively*. It removes all the files in the directory first. It's possible to mount a device on multiple mount points simultaneously. If the new home partition was still (or automatically) mounted on `/media/home` when you ran that command, then its contents are removed. That it was also mounted on `/home` does not prevent this.

This also explains the `rm: cannot remove ‘/media/home’: Device or resource busy` error. After removing everything inside `/media/home` (i.e., all the files on the partition mounted at that mount point), `rm` attempted to remove `/media/home` itself. But a directory that has a filesystem mounted on it cannot be removed; attempting to do so always fails with a "Device or resource busy" error.

`/media/home` was a mount point. It didn't really contain any files, it was just a place in one filesystem to attach the contents of another filesystem. When nothing is mounted on it, it should be empty. Therefore, `rm -r` is not necessary for removing it--you don't need to recursively delete something when it has no contents to recurse. The usual `rmdir` command is sufficient to remove an empty directory that is not being used.

Next time, do two things differently to ensure this problem does not recur:

1. Ensure nothing is mounted on `/media/home` before you attempt to remove it. To see what is currently mounted and where, you can run `mount`. Or just run:

   ```
   sudo umount /media/home
   ```

   That command is harmless even if the mount point is not being used. (Also, you should pay attention to the output. If the filesystem is currently being accessed through that mount point, it *won't* unmount the filesystem--but it will tell you that it has failed.)

   This is really mainly to ensure that the `/media/home` mountpoint actually *can* be removed. But it will also prevent you from accidentally deleting the contents of the new home partition.
2. Once you are ready to remove the `/media/home` mount point, use this command:

   ```
   sudo rmdir /media/home
   ```

   By using that command instead of a recursive `rm`, you avoid deleting anything inside, in case you have made a mistake and something exists inside.

   This is for safety. Using `rm -r` would work too, but if you made a mistake, you can remove more than you intend. (It is good general practice to avoid `rm -r ...` anytime you know or believe that `rmdir ...` will suffice.)

Finally, note that removing your old `/media/home` mount point is *a totally unrelated step* from [removing the backup of your old home directory residing on the original partition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving#Deleting_the_old_Home). For that, you do have to use `rm -r /old_home`, because there the goal is actually to delete a bunch of files rather than merely an empty directory.

Comment: Thanks man, that makes perfect sense. Those two simple steps should be added to that guide, shouldn't they? for dummies like me.  I'll see if there is a way to suggest it. THANK YOU SO MUCH.